# How to make a kind of synoptic table

Tags: reactjs

Excuse me for having to ask, but the following topic is costing me a lot.
I want to make a table with connections, but I can't find the formula to do it, and I couldn't find any example, I tried to find an example and copy its code but it doesn't convince me either. This is what I want to do:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCX2Z.png)
The idea is that, this is how I currently have it:
`

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import MundialButtons from "../../componentes/mundial-buttons";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    minWidth: 100,
    maxWidth: 250,
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  bullet: {
    display: "inline-block",
    margin: "0 2px",
    transform: "scale(0.8)"
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.primary
  },
  logo: {
    float: "left"
  }
}));

export default function Two() {
  const url =
    "https://adad1EUmIOwosuGTI7L2DD6S02RjOG7vbxU3FjVVD1u-iYiw/a!A1:Z1000";
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState();
  const fetchApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseJSON = await response.json();
    setTodos(responseJSON);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchApi();
  }, []);

  const classes = useStyles();
  const styleRed2 = [
    { marginTop: "90px" },
    { marginTop: "180px" },
    { marginTop: "270px" }
  ];

  return (
    <div id="all">
      <MundialButtons />

      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <Typography>asd</Typography>
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
      <div id="all">
        {!todos
          ? "Cargando..."
          : todos.map((todo, index) => {
              return (
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <div className={classes.root} id="octavos">
                    {todo.Local === undefined ||
                    todo.Local === "" ||
                    todo.Visitante === undefined ||
                    todo.Visitante === "" ? (
                      <div></div>
                    ) : (
                      <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
                        <CardContent>
                          <Typography
                            className={classes.title}
                            color="textSecondary"
                            gutterBottom
                          >
                            Octavos:
                          </Typography>

                          <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            test
                          </Typography>
                          <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                            test
                          </Typography>

                          {/*<Typography
                            className={classes.pos}
                            color="textSecondary"
                          >
                            hora
                          </Typography>*/}
                        </CardContent>
                      </Card>
                    )}

                    <p></p>
                  </div>
                </Grid>
              );
            })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`

A box with connections between them

Comment: It would help to describe what is wrong with the existing code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to lean on open-source libraries for this, no need to reinvent the wheel. As it happens, what you require kind of already exists: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@g-loot/react-tournament-brackets. [Demo.](https://sleepy-kare-d8538d.netlify.app/?path=/story/components-bracket--bracket)

Comment: Yes, something like that, but it's not exactly that, because I want to use my design, and I know it could be adapted, but no, I want to, because I already have a whole site built with the same design, and I'd like it to stay the same.

Comment: That's fair. However, surprisingly, you don't need to adapt the libraries CSS to your design in order to achieve consistency (which you are right, would be too annoying -- you don't want parallel styling anywhere that diverts from the canonical theme source). Instead, you can literally configure it such that it uses your original components. See under the header "Basic example of custom match component" in the readme. You would replace the divs etc with your own components.

Comment: There I am seeing, but where can you get the source code that generates?

Comment: I was trying it, but it is very bad for me, it looks like an iframe, to scroll from a cell phone you have to do it from a corner, because from the `SVGViewer` box it does not work, everything is very outdated. Isn't there something more modern, cleaner and that works well?

Comment: I'm still the same, can't it be solved? Any library that doesn't look like flash?